# Debugging app.config file in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

While executing the c# project on VS 2015, the following exception shows up:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Here is the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration>  
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,
EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->   </configSections> 
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="project_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider
connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user
id=root;password=rootpass;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=project_db&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />   </connectionStrings>  
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />   </startup>   <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,
EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>   </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: that connection string seems wrong.

Comment: That `&quot;` shouldn't be there. It should be quotation itself in connection string part.